# why the django static file not loading

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

settings.py

```
   import os
   BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
   DEBUG = True
   ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
       'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
       'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'authn',
              ]

   STATIC_URL = '/static/'
   STATICFILES_DIRS=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
     ]

       MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
     ]

      ROOT_URLCONF = 'first.urls'
      TEMPLATES = [
     {
           'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
             ],
            },
           },
           ]
```

urls.py

```
   from django.contrib import admin
   from django.urls import path
   from django.conf.urls.static import static
   from . import views

  urlpatterns = [
        path('',views.home,name="home"),
        path('register/', views.registerPage, name="register"),
       path('login/', views.loginPage, name="login"),
        path('logout/', views.logoutUser, name="logout"),
     ]
```

html file i am trying to work on

```html
<head>
    <title>Nura Admin - Charts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href= "{% static 'assets/images/atomic.png'%}">
    <link href="{% static 'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'%}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="{% static 'assets/font-awesome/css/all.css'%}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href=" {%static 'assets/css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{%static 'assets/plugins/chart.js/Chart.min.css'%}" />
</head>
```

files location

[image]

on run server getting

```
[29/Apr/2021 04:03:15] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[29/Apr/2021 04:03:15] "GET /login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 200 21957
[29/Apr/2021 04:03:16] "GET /static/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1710
[29/Apr/2021 04:03:16] "GET /static/assets/js/modernizr.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1704
[29/Apr/2021 04:03:16] "GET /static/assets/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1686
[29/Apr/2021 04:03:16] "GET /static/assets/js/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1695
[29/Apr/2021 04:03:16] "GET /static/assets/plugins/chart.js/Chart.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1737
[29/Apr/2021 04:03:16] "GET /static/assets/font-awesome/css/all.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1719
[29/Apr/2021 04:03:16] "GET /static/assets/js/moment.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1695
[29/Apr/2021 04:03:16] "GET /static/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1704
[29/Apr/2021 04:03:16] "GET /static/assets/js/popper.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1695
[29/Apr/2021 04:03:16] "GET /static/assets/js/detect.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1683
[29/Apr/2021 04:03:16] "GET /static/assets/js/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1695
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to the end of your "urlpatterns" variable in URLS.py:

```
+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

so it should look like:

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('',views.home,name="home"),
        path('register/', views.registerPage, name="register"),
       path('login/', views.loginPage, name="login"),
        path('logout/', views.logoutUser, name="logout"),
     ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

then make sure you have the following in your settings.py:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

STATIC_ROOT = "/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: should i import the settings.py file to the urls.py ? cause it's showing errors in settings.static_url and settings.static_root

Comment: Yes.  You need to import settings into url.py